# How to load drop down list from Properties file in struts1.x

Tags: java, struts

I need to load a dropdown list from properties, and that drop down should be dynamic (We can add more values to that property file)

I am using struts1.x

I have done by the form that goes to action class and grabbing those from property files and setting in form, Instead of this way I need without going to action.

Comment: Have you tried using ResourceBundle?

Comment: ResourceBundle In jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> html:messages

tag.

```
<html:messages id="msg" bundle="Property_file">   
        <li><bean:write name="msg" /></li>
</html:messages>
```

Example can be found [here](http://www.niallp.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/HelpTagsErrorsAndMessages.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and this worked or similar/for reference you can use this

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>

 <h1 align="center" > </h1>

 <%

    ResourceBundle messages =ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");

    Enumeration messageKeys = messages.getKeys();

 %>

 <table align="center" >

 <tr>

   <td> Select User:</td>

    <td>

    <select name="user" >

  <%

   while(messageKeys.hasMoreElements()){

   String key = (String)messageKeys.nextElement();

   String value = messages.getString(key);

 %>

 <option value="<%=messages.getString(key)%>">

 <%=messages.getString(key)%>

 </option>

<%

   }

%>

</select>

</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

And using tag, i am using following tag with corresponding key for just accessing it in jsp page,

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/taglibs/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>

   <bean:message bundle="bundle_name" key="your_key"/>
```

Comment: Sorry I might have led you in wrong direction.. I dont want to Use Scriplets in my JSP  I am just Searching for tags which I can read from property file

Comment: @looser can you post your property file content(keys,values)?